# Loop through products and return first product that matches criteria

Tags: php, array

I am writing a function which loops through an array of products.  The function needs to return:

- the ID of the first product that `has an image` and is `in stock`
- if no products have an image and are in stock, then return the first product id that `has an image`
- if no products have an image, then return the first product id that is `in stock`
- if no products have an image, and no products are in stock, return the `first product id`

This is what I have written, and it is working as expected:

```
function loopThroughProducts($products)
{
    $firstId = $products[0]->id;

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($product->hasImage && $product->inStock) {
            $id = $product->id;
            return $id;
        }
        if ($product->hasImage && empty($firstIdWithImage)) {
            $firstIdWithImage = $product->id;
        }
        if ($product->inStock && empty($firstIdInStock)) {
            $firstIdInStock = $product->id;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($firstIdWithImage)) {
        return $firstIdWithImage;
    }
    if (!empty($firstIdInStock)) {
        return $firstIdInStock;
    }

    return $firstId;
}
```

Does anyone see a way that I can optimize this loop or simplify the logic?  I dislike using so many sequential `if`-statements in one function, and there are some minor violations to the DRY principle.

Comment: I have always heard if you are indenting more than twice in a function or have lots of if..else you should separate this functionality. If this is part of a class you could break all of these into methods that are more flexible and testable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I believe you are referring to [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).  For our project, if-statements nested within a loop are generally acceptable.  Any additional nesting would certainly provoke ancillary private methods as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Clean, readable code. But why not use more of PHP's standard array functions? Use the array_search or in_array functions. Or -even more fancy- the array_filter function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Those are definitely viable options if I was matching only one set of criteria.  However, since I am matching on a few different criteria (as described in the bullet points of my question), my function conveniently returns all the matches I need in one loop.  If I used `array_search` or `in_array`, I would be searching (looping through) the same array at least three times, and this would not be as performant.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can certainly nest your checks a bit better to improve DRYness.
- `isset()` has an advantage over `empty()` in this scenario because `isset()` accepts multiple parameters versus `empty()` only permits a single parameter.
- using a chain of null coalescing operators will reduce the lines of code near the end of your custom function.  Here is [a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654483) to this technique.

For anyone who got lost in your explanation of the logic:

1. Has Image, Has Stock -- use as soon as found
2. Has Image, No Stock -- use if no #1 is found in whole array
3. No Image, Has Stock -- use if no #2 is found in whole array
4. No Image, No Stock -- use default if no #3 is found in whole array

Logically, there is no reason to store an id that qualifies as #3 if a #2 id is already found.

Code: (not tested because no test data provided)

```
function loopThroughProducts($products) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($product->hasImage) {
            if ($product->inStock) {
                return $product->id;
            } elseif (!isset($hasImageNoStock)) {
                $hasImageNoStock = $product->id;
            }
        } elseif ($product->inStock && !isset($hasImageNoStock, $hasStockNoImage)) {
            $hasStockNoImage = $product->id;
        }
    }
    return $hasImageNoStock ?? $hasStockNoImage ?? $products[0]->id;
}
```